# Different DataFrames need to compare and add new value

Tags: python, pandas

I've two Dataframes

1. DF1 = Contains (~30 Columns and 15000 entries) relevant are "TYP" (string) and "VERSION" (string)
2. DF2 = Contains "SOFTWARE_NAME" (string), "VERSION" (string) and "EOS" (date)

Now I'd like to add in DF1 additional columns "EOS_DATE" (date), "EOS" (bool)
if

```
  DF1['TYP'] == DF2['SOFTWARE_NAME'] &
  DF1['VERSION'] == DF2['VERSION']
```

then

```
  DF1['EOS_DATE'] = DF2['EOS']
  DF1['EOS'] = if DF2['EOS'] < now() then True else False
```

I've tried with np, pd.where(~) but running mainly in this issue:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: To perform this comparison it's important to know how the two dataframe relate to each other (if at all). Is there a key that can be used to connect the two or is there some other way to relate the two dataframes?

Comment: This is a code question. You can totally post in on Stack Overflow, with "Pandas" tag, you might get a bit more answers

Comment: @Oxbowerce ... they are build separately from different sources. The only common what they have is the TYP <-> SOFTWARE_NAME and VERSION <-> VERSION. No other keys available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your columns values, so you won't have any issue (my goal is to make only one dataframe)

```
DF2 = DF2.rename(columns={"EOS": "DF2_EOS", "VERSION": "DF2_VERSION"})
```

Then you want to apply a change only for lines valuing your conditions. The best to do is to merge your dataframes, keeping all your DF1 rows (ie : standard merge) :

```
DF1 = DF1.merge(DF2, left_on=['TYP', 'VERSION'], right_on=['SOFTWARE_NAME', 'DF2_VERSION'])
```

Finally make your changes :

```
DF1.loc[DF1['DF2_EOS'] < pandas.to_datetime('today').normalize(), 'EOS'] = True
DF1.loc[DF1['DF2_EOS'] >= pandas.to_datetime('today').normalize(), 'EOS'] = False
DF1 = DF1.rename(columns={"DF2_EOS": "EOF_DATE"})
```

Comment: Instead of two `loc` assignments for `True` and `False`, you should be able to assign a single boolean Series: `DF1['EOS'] = DF1['DF2_EOS'] < pd.to_datetime('now').normalize()`

Comment: Hard to confirm without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/13138364), though.

Comment: @tdy -- Understand, promise to describe better the next time.